# Is there a way to get Hostnames with Scapy in Python?

Tags: python, scapy

I made a simple IP Scanner which I use to scan the Local Network. I want to get the Hostname like Nmap. Is there a way to get every Hostname in the local network with scapy.all? Here is my Python Script where I want insert the Hostname:

````
import scapy.all as scapy


request = scapy.ARP()
broadcast = scapy.Ether()
broadcast.dst = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'
available_networks = []


def IP_Scan(net_area, net_mask):
    available_networks.clear()
    request.pdst = f'{net_area}/{net_mask}'
    request_broadcast = broadcast / request
    clients = scapy.srp(request_broadcast, timeout=5)[0]
    for sent_ip, received_ip in clients:

        available_networks.append({'IP': received_ip.psrc, 'MAC': received_ip.hwsrc})

    return available_networks```
````

Comment: You import `scapy`, not `scipy`.  Correct the tags, and title..

Comment: I can't edit it anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scapy doesn't provide that because it already exists via Python's `socket` module:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import socket

request = scapy.ARP()
broadcast = scapy.Ether()
broadcast.dst = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'
available_networks = []


def IP_Scan(net_area, net_mask):
    available_networks.clear()
    request.pdst = f'{net_area}/{net_mask}'
    request_broadcast = broadcast / request
    clients = scapy.srp(request_broadcast, timeout=5)[0]
    for sent_ip, received_ip in clients:

        available_networks.append({'IP': received_ip.psrc, 
                                   'MAC': received_ip.hwsrc, 
                                   'HOSTNAME': socket.gethostbyaddr(received_ip.psrc)[0]})

    return available_networks
```

In the code `'HOSTNAME': socket.gethostbyaddr(received_ip.psrc)[0]`, you need index zero to get the hostname. Add checks in case that's missing in the returns.